# Hosting Laravel Locally

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have built an application which is used by a number of staff internally, I have hosted the app locally on a machine next to my desktop and I've done this by

```
php artisan serve --host 10.111.0.01 --port 1111
```

This allows everybody to access over the same network.

This works great, however recently we are seeing a few resource issues on the application. Taking too long to load, randomly crashing etc. This is more than likely due to the number of active users.

Which method would be the best approach to hosting this application internally? is there a better way that php artisan serve?

Thanks

Comment: This question is quite broad. There are numerous ways of hosting a PHP application. nginx, Apache, lighttpd, to name major names, could all be of service to you.

Comment: The arisan serve command uses PHP's built in webserver which is typically used for development/testing/demonstration purposes. I'd really recommend using a webserver as mentioned by @bzeaman

Comment: We're happy to help, but what platform are you wondering about?

Comment: Apologies @bzeaman I have a web server running which i've used Xammp to get it started however I'm just confused on how to host a laravel application on a local xammp web server?

Comment: Xampp uses Apache. I take you're not using a database so you can disable MariaDB. For Apache: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/25/creating-an-apache-virtualhost

Comment: ever heard of forge ? if you are not familiar with server setup use something like forge to handle it for you it saves you time if you are quiet the explorer get a fresh install of ubuntu install php and apache (or nginx) make sure to have the hosts setup dns configured etc. or use something like http://rocketeer.autopergamene.eu/I-Introduction/Whats-Rocketeer.html

Comment: @Sari Yono I do not think Forge is wanted here because he mentions 'internally'.

Comment: I'm going to try your method @bzeaman thanks for the info

Comment: Thanks @SariYono I am familiar with forge as I use this for my hosted applications, it's internally I've struggled with

Comment: Hey @bzeaman it seems to be doing what I'm after :) thank you for your help so far. I can now access my project via the local apache server using xampp and performance is better. My question now is how do other computers on the same network access my server? prior they use to use 10.111.0.47:1111

Comment: The address is probably the same, but the port may have changed. By default it's 80, so you might try 10.111.0.47:80 (you can leave out :80, because every browser assumes it). If you want your configuration to have 1111, look at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html#ipport and use 1111 instead of 8080.

Comment: Thanks @bzeaman that's sorted it!

Comment: @Wolrab No problem! I've tried to summarise it into an answer so it hopefully benefits other people in the future. You may accept it, or edit/comment on it if it's wrong!

Comment: you could do the same thing with forge if you have a subscription use forge to handle your local server too i have Digital ocean boxes and also vps servers that are local forge can handle both. ease of mind @bzeaman

Comment: @Sari Yono I'm not sure I understand. Forge is not something you install, right?

Comment: under Create Server click on custom VPS nad just make sure that you have the ubuntu freshly installed on that server heres the requirement: Your custom server must run a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04 x64 and must have a root user.
and you can follow the instructions there. let me know if you need any more assistant @bzeaman

Comment: @Sari Yono I do not use it, nor want to use it. I just want to clear up a misunderstanding I appear to have. If I understand correctly, Forge will install something for you? With SSH or something similar?

Comment: it provisions your server yes, you simply install the OS and it takes care of Provisioning it for you installing Nginx > 1.9
PHP 7.0
MySQL & Postgres
Redis
Memcached
Beanstalk
Node
and more in addition to securing your network etc. you have to run a shell file that forge provide you with. @bzeaman

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121620/discussion-between-bzeaman-and-sari-yono).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is quite broad. There are numerous ways of hosting a PHP application. nginx, Apache, lighttpd, to name major names, could all be of service to you.

Assuming Windows, there is an ideal tool called [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html). You only need Apache, as with `artisan serve` the only thing is needed is to serve the PHP files.

The best is to create a file in `apache2/sites-available`. For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:1111>
  ServerName 10.111.0.01
  DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\laravel\public"
  <Directory "C:\xampp\laravel\public">
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then restart Apache.